# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name but all setting seems proper

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, data-binding

I have this major problem in my site. Hence I checked all my codes place in side many times but it seems all fine.

E.g. on [this page](http://healthsaviour.com/chemists) it shows this error

```
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'chemistID'.
```

I checked my table column name which is same. Also inside code I checked column name is correct. I checked in side Listview code & it was correct. Still it's showing error. Following is my ListView & data binding codes.

```
<asp:ListView ID="chemists" runat="server" DataKeyNames="chemistID" DataKey="chemistID">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                <!--list-content-blocks-starts--><div class="list-content-blocks">
                                    <!--list-data-starts--><div class="list-data">
                                    <!--head-title-starts--><div class="head-title">
                                        <h3><asp:HyperLink ID="name" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "chemist-details?chemistID=" + Eval("chemistID").ToString() %>' Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'>HyperLink</asp:HyperLink></h3>
                                        <div class="list-address">
                                            <asp:Label ID="address" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("address") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            <%--<asp:Label ID="street" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("streetName") %>'></asp:Label>,
                                            <asp:Label ID="area" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("areaName") %>'></asp:Label>,
                                            <asp:Label ID="city" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("city") %>'></asp:Label>,
                                            <asp:Label ID="zip" runat="server" Text=  '<%# Eval("zipCode") %>'></asp:Label>.--%>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!--head-title-ends-->

                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                    <!--content-in-starts--><div class="content-in">
                                        <!--contenr-dp-starts--><div class="content-dp">
                                            <img id="thumbnail" runat="server" src='<%# Eval("thumbnail") %>' />
                                        </div><!--content-dp-ends-->

                                        <!--content-other-details-starts--><div class="content-other-details">
                                            <section class="known-for">
                                                    <ul class="bestFor">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="knownFor" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("products")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                        <li class="showMore"><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "chemist-details?chemistID=" + Eval("chemistID").ToString() %>' Text="More"></asp:HyperLink></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                            </section>


                                            <!--list-time-starts--><div class="list-time">
                                                <div class="list-time-inner">WORKING HOURS &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                                                    <asp:Label ID="opdFrom" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("slot1From") %>'></asp:Label> To 
                                                    <asp:Label ID="opdTo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("slot1To") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                                            </div><!--list-time-ends-->

                                            <%-- <!--list-time-starts--><div class="feesC">
                                                <div class="fees-inner"><asp:Label ID="consulting" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("consultancyFees") %>'></asp:Label> / Doctor</div>
                                            </div><!--list-time-ends-->--%>

                                            <!--sms-button-starts--><div class="sms-button">
                                                <asp:Button ID="getSMS" CssClass="get-sms" runat="server" Text="Get SMS" />
                                            </div><!--sms-button-ends-->

                                        </div><!--content-other-details-ends-->
                                    </div><!--content-in-ends-->
                                        </div><!--list-data-ends-->

                                    <!--rating-show-starts--><div class="rating-show">
                                        <div class="rating-show-inner">
                                            <div class="show-rating vote1"><asp:Label ID="lblRating" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
                                            <div class="show-votes"><asp:label ID="totalVotes" runat="server"></asp:label> <asp:Label ID="seeVote" runat="server" Text="Vote"></asp:Label></div>
                                        </div>

                                        <%--<div class="rating-show-inner">
                                            <div class="show-rating rank1"><span>8</span></div>
                                            <div class="show-votes">in Pune</div>
                                        </div>--%>
                                    </div><!--rating-show-ends-->
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div><!--list-content-blocks-ends-->
                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                        <div class="not-found">
                                            <p>Sorry! Selected Query Not Found</p>
                                            <center><img src="images/not-found.jpg"</center>
                                        </div>
                                    </EmptyDataTemplate>

                                    <LayoutTemplate>
                                        <ul id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
                                            <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                                        </ul> 
                                    </LayoutTemplate>
                                    </asp:ListView>

                                <div class="datapager" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PageSize="10" PagedControlID="chemists" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                                        <Fields>
                                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                                                ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                                            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
                                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
                                        </Fields>
                                    </asp:DataPager>
                                </div>
```

DataBind code

```
    Private Sub chemists_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
        chemists.DataSource = GetData()
        chemists.DataBind()
    End Sub

Private Function GetData() As Data.DataTable
        Try
            If Session("Data") IsNot Nothing Then
                Return Session("Data")
            Else
                DataPager1.SetPageProperties(0, DataPager1.PageSize, False) 'reinit
                Dim citySelector As Label = Page.Master.FindControl("locationPopupActivator")
                Using con As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString)
                    Dim cmd As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("SELECT chemistID, name, address, thumbnail, slot1From, slot1To, products FROM chemists where city like @city and status = 'active'", con)
                    cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = citySelector.Text & "%" 'same as Session("masterLocation")
                    Dim table As New Data.DataTable()
                    Dim da As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    da.Fill(table)
                    countItems.Text = table.Rows.Count().ToString
                    da.Dispose()
                    cmd.Dispose()
                    Session("Data") = table
                    Return table
                End Using
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex) 'for debug purpose
            Return Nothing
        End Try

    End Function
```

Comment: Please don't post code snippets with huge wads of whitespace before them.  It just makes it hard for us to read.  Use the Alt key while selecting to enable you to select a block of code anywhere and thus exclude the whitespace before all the lines.

Comment: Make absolutely sure you have a column named "chemistID" in the table "chemists". Also, you could try keeping DataKeyNames but getting rid of the DataKey property and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project to try and recreate your problem. I created a database table named "chemists" with a primary key of "chemistID" and the other fields seen in your Select statement. I used a MS SQL database instead of MySQL, and removed the `DataKey` attribute from the ListView, which I think was intended to be `DataKeys`?

I changed the name of the table in the database to "chemists2", and received a SQL error when the SQL command was executed, but this is a different error than the one you posted.

I then changed the DataKeyNames attribute of the ListView, and then I did receive the same error you did. I changed DataKeyNames to "chemistID3", like this: `<asp:ListView ID="chemists" runat="server" DataKeyNames="chemistID3">`, and ran the code, which made the error, "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'chemistID3'."

I resolved this error by changing the `Eval("chemistID")` lines (there are two of them inside the ListView) to `Eval("chemistID3")`. At this point I was not getting your error, but was again getting the SQL error. I then changed every instance of chemistID to chemistID3, and everything started working again.

So to summarize: the chemistID column in your database table must exactly match the column in your SELECT statement, and must match the DataKeyNames attribute, and must match what the Eval() expressions are looking for. I would recommend refreshing your database and making sure the columns are what you expect them to be. I would also recommend rebuilding the project. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution. There was nothing wrong with my code. I have number of pages with same name as session(Data). The thing was creating problem was on each pages session(data) was storing different information. I just changed name of session on each page so it didn't override with each other.